# Odd primes of the form $\varphi(m)^{2k+1}+1$

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function

With $\varphi(m)$ for $m\ge1$ being Euler's totient function, I am curious to know if are known odd primes of the form
$$1+\varphi(m)^\lambda\tag1$$
where $\lambda=2k+1>1$ is an *odd* integer.

> **Question.** Do you know from the literature if there exists an odd prime with the form in $(1)$? And do you know why it is so difficult to find them? If it was in the literature please answer this question as a reference request and I try to find and read those examples from the literature. **Many thanks.**

Comment: About the second question *And do you know why is so difficult to find such odd primes?* only is required provide us a reasonig to convince us that seems that there are few of such primes of mentioned type.

Comment: Many thanks for the improvements @ParclyTaxel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No odd primes of the given form can exist, since
$$\varphi(m)^{2k+1}+1=(\varphi(m)+1)(\varphi(m)^{2k}-\varphi(m)^{2k-1}+\dots+1)$$
with $\varphi(m)+1\ge2$ and $\varphi(m)^{2k+1}>\varphi(m)$ for $m>2,k\ge1$. (If $m\le2$ then $\varphi(m)^{2k+1}+1=2$.)

Comment: Many thanks I am going to read and study your nice answer. 
I suspected that there should be a reasoning for as much evidence as I had calculated, but I was not able to write your reasoning.